# Applying device orientation to the camera in a three.js application

Tags: javascript, three.js, virtual-reality

I'm currently working on a three.js VR project and ive gotten the cameras' orientation hooked up to the camera but my problem is that the default device orientation makes it so when the device is laying flat on the table it looks straight out like this:
https://imgur.com/YGzGQBI&ClydB4D#0

and I would like the orientation to be when the device is laying flat it looks like this so you are looking at the ground:
https://imgur.com/YGzGQBI&ClydB4D#1

here is my javascript that im using to make this happen.

```
camera.rotation.x = e.beta * Math.PI / 180;
```

Comment: Are you using `THREE.DeviceOrientationControls`?

Comment: no i didnt know about that.  I just used javascript

Comment: Give it a try. All the math is done for you. See the three.js examples.